# how to get a campaign id from marketing api

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-ads-api, facebook-marketing-api

getCampaigns - this is giving all the campaign id's of an ad account. but is there a way to get/fetch a single campaign id. Because I am working on a project, in which I would like to know whether the ad account is having a particular campaign id or not.
with getCampaigns it gives all the campaign id's (25 per call) and paging. in this case, is there a way to find my campaign id present or not?

Comment: you can try to call `/<campaign-id>` or use the `filtering` options

Comment: I have tried this https://graph.facebook.com/v3.2/act_12345600009/90123909239232?access_token=<accesstoken> but it throws  "message": "Unknown path components: /90123909239232"

Comment: sorry I mean without the adAccount like [v3.2/campaing-id](https://graph.facebook.com/v3.2/90123909239232?access_token=<accesstoken>) you will get the campaign detail or a permission error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the filtering options as example:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/v3.2/act_<account-id>/campaigns?filtering=[{'field':'id','operator':'IN','value':["<campaign-id>"]}]&fields=name,effective_status?access_token=<accesstoken>
```

Or simply try to access to the campaign using the objectId:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/v3.2/<campaign-id>?access_token=<accesstoken>
```

but in this case, if the user haven't access or the campaign doesn't exists the endpoint return a generic error.

Comment: Hi @WinimyTech you are welcome! which one satisfy your needed?

Comment: Hi @Matteo actually both worked well, for now I have used the second option.